# Angularjs - controller inheritance with child scope?

Tags: angularjs, inheritance

I'm trying achieve multiple controller inheritance in angular.

I've setup a simplified demonstration of what i'm trying to achieve in this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/piradelo/1/edit).

I'm trying to implement prototypical inheritance from one controller and create a child scope from another. In the example provided - `outputCtrl` should be a parent or allow me to decorate some of it's functions.

I can achieve this by nesting the controllers in the DOM

```
<div ng-controler='parentCtrl'>
  <div ng-controler='outputCtrl'>
    <div ng-controler='outputChildCtrl'>
```

and decorate via `$scope.$parent.process_input`. Problem is that this pattern is repeated several times and i'm trying to keep the inheritance in the code (and not the DOM).

The desired result in `outputChildCtrl` should enable :

```
  $scope.proccess_input = function() {
    // call outputCtrl.process_input here

    // continue processing in child ctrl
    $scope.result = $scope.processing_function($scope.result);
    console.log('outputChildCtrl processing ',$scope.result);
  };
```

**EDIT**

From the comments is see that the case is not so clear. The use case is of different form controls. I have a controller handling an input field (validation, formatting, setting etc), an output field (formatting, watch on result etc) - each of these controllers is used independently. The third field is a composition of the two controllers - input and output field. The implementation of the input is the same so prototypical inheritance is enough but the output requires some composition on one function - the `proccess_input` function in the jsbin. I'm currently using angular's prototypical inheritance as illustrated in the sample HTML above - problems with this approach are

- Each input output field is creating three scopes - unnecessary.
- Every time i want to use this field i need to explicitly declare it in the DOM with three ng-controller div's - no so DRY.

I trying to move this behavior to the code instead of the DOM and save the two scope's along the way.

Hope this clarify the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You've spelled controller incorrectly.

Comment: First, why can't you use directives? They automatically inherit parent scope. Second, does the `process_output` function provide common functionality? This sounds like a use case for a shared service. In my opinion, you should shy away from using inheritance from the `$parent` . This generally is a bad design pattern which makes your views all dependent on their parent views in ways that make them horrible candidates for re-use throughout the application.

Comment: Angular scope has prototypal inheritance. You don't need to manage inheritance on your own. Go here https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes and read the section on it. It's pretty well written. Also, find and use some of the debugging tools that show you the scope construction so you can see what is available in your scope. Batarang for Chrome and there is now an extension for Firefox that does an adequate job.

Comment: @Mike , Steve Davis - i've edited the original post with some further explanations - keep in mind this is a simplified example of the problem. The actual controllers contain a lot of functionality and are used independently.